# * at the end of an URL

Tags: string, url

I am trying to print to the console an URL that is directly clickable, problem is, when I have a star ( * ) character at the end of the url, it is not included in the url "clickable" part. As an examle:

`println "https://myUrl.com/myEndpoint&myParam=*"`

produces

https://myUrl.com/myEndpoint&myParam=*

I think this is not related to the programming language but to how links are dislplayed, is there a way to make it immediately clickable, without copying and pasting it?

Comment: replace `*` with `%2A`  - that's url-encoding representation of this char

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the terminal program you are using to display the URL, and how it decides what to make "clickable". As such, I think it's off-topic for this site, and would be better suited (with appropriate information about what program you're using) for superuser.com